# Make a MySQL SELECT and INNER JOIN faster

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have the following query which works as it should, but I'd like to know how I can make it run faster.

For `info`, tables `cl`, `jo` and `mi` all have column `ref` as the `auto_inc` `primary key` and `ID` as the main identification number.  Therefore, I use the `ref`s to keep a history of changes for `ID`.  So, I use `SELECT MAX(ref) FROM [xx] GROUP BY ID` to get the most recent `cl` `jo` and `mi`.

```
SELECT mi.ref, jo.ID, mi.ID AS mID, mt.mi_type, jo.ref, jt.jo_type, cl.cl_name 
FROM mi 
INNER JOIN mt ON mt.ref = mi.mi_type
INNER JOIN jo ON jo.ID = mi.job
INNER JOIN cl ON cl.ID = jo.cl
INNER JOIN jt ON jt.ref = jo.jo_type
WHERE mi.ref IN (SELECT MAX(ref) 
                    FROM mi 
                    GROUP BY ID)
AND jo.ref IN (SELECT MAX(ref)
                    FROM jo
                    GROUP BY ID)
AND cl.ref IN (SELECT MAX(ref)
                    FROM cl
                    GROUP BY ID)
ORDER BY cl.cl_name, jt.jo_type, mt.mi_type ASC
```

Comment: Have you tried selecting the MAX from each of three tables first then using those values in the where clause?

Comment: No but I'll give it a go.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Anthony for pointing me in the right direction, I then realised that I had unnecessary joins so here's the much quicker final version, for reference:

```
SELECT mi2.ref, jo2.ID, mi2.ID AS mID, mt.mi_type, jo2.ref, jt.jo_type, cl2.cl_name
FROM (SELECT ID, MAX(ref) AS ref, mi_type, job FROM mi GROUP BY ID) mi2
INNER JOIN mt ON mt.ref = mi2.mi_type
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(ref) AS ref, cl, jo_type FROM jo GROUP BY ID) jo2 ON jo2.ID = mi2.job
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(ref) AS ref, cl_name FROM cl GROUP BY ID) cl2 ON cl2.ID = jo2.cl
INNER JOIN jt ON jt.ref = jo2.jo_type
ORDER BY cl2.cl_name, jt.jo_type, mt.mi_type ASC
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Moving your subqueries to the *from* clause may improve performance.

Additional indexes may help too. Add a clustered index on *ID* or (*ID, ref*) for tables *mi*, *jo* and *cl* to speed up the *group by* and *max* operations. You may also benefit from a clustered index on each of your *order by* columns.

```
SELECT mi.ref, jo.ID, mi.ID AS mID, mt.mi_type, jo.ref, jt.jo_type, cl.cl_name 
FROM mi 
INNER JOIN mt ON mt.ref = mi.mi_type
INNER JOIN jo ON jo.ID = mi.job
INNER JOIN cl ON cl.ID = jo.cl
INNER JOIN jt ON jt.ref = jo.jo_type
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ref) AS ref FROM mi GROUP BY ID) mi2 ON mi2.ref = mi.ref
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ref) AS ref FROM jo GROUP BY ID) jo2 ON jo2.ref = jo.ref
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ref) AS ref FROM cl GROUP BY ID) cl2 ON cl2.ref = cl.ref
ORDER BY cl.cl_name, jt.jo_type, mt.mi_type
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be any quicker.  Can I ask you to explain why matching on `ID` as well as on `ref` (the primary key) improves the performance?

Comment: Quite right. I overlooked that `ref` is the primary key. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, but it hasn't made the query any quicker.